# Nao consigo chamar uma Activity atraves de um Fragment

Tags: android

Antes de tudo perdao pelos erros (teclado bugado).

Bom estou tentanto chamar uma Activity atraves do codigo abaixo, este codigo esta na minha MainActivity.java. Criei os fragments para serem chamados atraves do Menu Drawer e funciona perfeitamente.
O meu objetivo e conseguir chamar uma Activity diretamente desse menu mas nao funciona, o aplicativo compila executa certinho mas quando toco no item desejado (sobre) o app trava.

Estou usando esse codigo para tentar chamar a ActivitySobre.

```
Intent iSobre = new Intent(this, ActivitySobre.class);
startActivity(iSobre);
```

Ja procurei e encontrei codigos como o getActivity(), porem isso nao funciona.

MainActivity.java

```
private void displaySelectedScreen(int id){
    android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment = null;

    switch (id){
        case R.id.nav_home:
            fragment = new FragmentHome();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_notificacao:
            fragment = new FragmentNotificacao();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_favorito:
            fragment = new FragmentFavoritos();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_minhaconta:
            fragment = new FragmentMinhaConta();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_share:
            fragment = new FragmentSobre();
            break;
        case R.id.item_sobre:
            Intent iSobre = new Intent(this, ActivitySobre.class);
            startActivity(iSobre);
            //fragment = new FragmentSobre();
            break;
    }

    if(fragment != null){
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content_main, fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }
```

Alguem tem ideia de como se resolver isso?
Desde ja agradeco.

Comment: O que acontece quando você faz? 

Intent iSobre = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivitySobre.class);
                getActivity().startActivity(iSobre);

Comment: Estou executando o app direto no meu celular. 
Quando toco ele trava e informa "O AppTeste parou".
So isso.

Comment: Tu pode pegar o log no android studio na aba RUN quando der problema e ver exatamente qual o problema!

Comment: Ok, so um momento, vou fazer isso.

Comment: Antonio, sei la que diabos aconteceu. 
Estou a mais ou menos uma semana tentando fazer isso funcionar e quando fui depurar o codigo ele compilou e executou normalmente.
Consegui abrir a Activity.

Comment: Estranho.
O que voce acha que pode ser?

Comment: Você modificou algo no código? O que poderia acontecer é que ele precisa do parent context então você teria que passar o getActivity().startActivity(iSobre);

Se você colocou esse trecho de código e funcionou, foi isso. Se não mexeu em nada eu não saberia dizer o que foi hahaha. Caso tenha sido isso, tu me diz que eu coloco como resposta.

Comment: A unica coisa que mudei foi que exclui uma linha de codigo da ActivitySobre.java
E redigitei esse codigo da intent e dei um Clean e um Rebuild.

Ja tentei usar o metodo informado por voce mas infelizmente nao funcionou.

Comment: ah blz, mas pelo menos agora tá funcionando aí, né?

Comment: talvez o erro estava na activity sobre e não no ato de abrir ela

Comment: Realmente, talvez tenha sido isso. Obrigado pela ajuda. Obrigado mesmo.